# Error while doing update 12.10 Ubuntu

Tags: updates

```
W:Failed to fetch http://deb.opera.com/opera/dists/lenny/non-free/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found
```

I have been seeing this error the last few days.. Any fixes?

Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 0):

The lenny directory has been removed.  Now at http://deb.opera.com/opera/dists/ we find only the following (Debian-related) directories:

```
sid/                    29-Nov-2012 14:21    -   
squeeze/                29-Nov-2012 14:21    -   
stable/                 29-Nov-2012 14:21    -   
testing/                29-Nov-2012 14:21    -   
unstable/               29-Nov-2012 14:21    -   
wheezy/                 29-Nov-2012 14:21    -
```